# Python doesn't have opcode cacher?

Tags: python, opcode, opcode-cache

I'm currently using PHP. I plan to start using Django for some of my next project.

But I don't have any experience with Python. After some searching, I still can't find a Python opcode cacher.

(There are lots of opcode cacher for PHP: APC, eAccelerator, Xcache, ...)

Answer (score 9):

It's automatic in Python -- a compiled `.pyc` file will appear magically.

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't need one the same way PHP needs it. Python doesn't throw the bytecode away after execution, it keeps it around (as .pyc files).

Answer (score 1):

It's built in: http://pyfaq.infogami.com/how-do-i-create-a-pyc-file

Python can compile to `*.pyc` files that effectively do the same thing.