# is there an accelerator for ruby as those for php

Tags: ruby, opcode-cache

I've been looking for accelerators for ruby like those for php(zend,xcache,...) but I couldn't find one, except this github repo : [ruby_accelerator](https://github.com/simonrussell/ruby_accelerator) which seems unmaintained(and I don't know if it's an opcode cacher or a code analysis tool).

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468243/python-doesnt-have-opcode-cacher) question which talks about python and that's this is built-in, I want to ask about ruby : is it built-in in ruby too ? if not are there ones for ruby ?.

### PS

I'm asking about MRI implementation latest version(which is 2.2.3 at the time of writing) and I'm not asking about VMs as zend,xcache,etc are not VMs.

Comment: No one-size-fits-all solution exists for Ruby. Are you experiencing an actual performance problem that you can tell us more about?

Comment: What is an accelerator? What does it do? What should it do in Ruby?